# XmlDocument not preserving whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument

`XmlDocument` is adding a space at the end of self closing tags, even with `PreserveWhitespace` set to `true`.

```
// This fails
string originalXml = "<sample><node id=\"99\"/></sample>";

// Convert to XML
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.LoadXml(originalXml);

// Save back to a string
string extractedXml = null;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    doc.Save(stream);

    stream.Position = 0;
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        extractedXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

// Confirm that they are identical
Assert.AreEqual(originalXml, extractedXml);
```

The desired output is:

```
<sample><node id="99"/></sample>
```

But I am getting:

```
<sample><node id="99" /></sample>
```

Is there a way to suppress that extra space?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it matter? The document is structurally the same either way.

Comment: .Save uses an XmlTextWriter internally and that extra space is documented behaviour

Comment: You can use [XNode.DeepEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to compare XML. Also see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/01/28/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees.aspx) article.

Comment: Dear @DougS, you are using one of the most space wasting data format already, one more byte per element won't make difference:).

Comment: Not just curiosity, the _why_ is crucial here. I think @AlexanderPetrov made a good guess but DogS should clarify.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov made a good guess, but a proper XML comparison isn't good enough for me: this is a piece of middleware accepting XML as a string from the outside, and being forced to store as an XML object in a repository. The external software is grumpy at a non-exact match when it comes back. Highly annoying

Comment: Make that part of the question. Because that space is irrelevant to Xml and XmlDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how `XmlDocument.Save(Stream)` looks like :

```
public virtual void Save(Stream outStream)
{
  XmlDOMTextWriter xmlDomTextWriter = new XmlDOMTextWriter(outStream, this.TextEncoding);
  if (!this.preserveWhitespace)
    xmlDomTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  this.WriteTo((XmlWriter) xmlDomTextWriter);
  xmlDomTextWriter.Flush();
}
```

So setting `PreserveWhiteSpace` has no effect on the inside of the nodes. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `XmlTextWriter` says :

> When writing an empty element, an additional space is added between tag name and the closing tag, for example . This provides compatibility with older browsers.

So I guess there is no easy way out. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491669/Remove-space-in-NET-serialization-of-empty-XML-ele)'s a workaround tho:

> So I wrote a wrapper class MtxXmlWriter that is derived from XmlWriter and wraps the original XmlWriter returned by XmlWriter.Create() and does all the necessary tricks.
>
> Instead of using XmlWriter.Create() you just call one of the MtxXmlWriter.Create() methods, that's all. All other methods are directly handed over to the encapsulated original XmlWriter except for WriteEndElement(). After calling WriteEndElement() of the encapsulated XmlWriter, " />" is replaced with "/>" in the buffer: